# Clearing SACSID cookie

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I'm working on a Python project on AppEngine and I just set up authentication via the `app.yaml` file (through specifying the option `login:admin`). The goal of this was to restrict a particular function of the app to only the specified app administrators. However, the persistent SACSID cookie that AppEngine sets upon authentication does not expire when the application admin logs out of his Google account.

Complicating things further, whenever I try to look at `document.cookie`, it comes up as `""`, witohut the SACSID cookie's information. How can I delete this cookie/how can I even access it?